# Changing record set weight in a hosted zone in Route53 using Python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

We have an hosted zone, with multiple records. There is two A records with weighted routing policy.

```
test.xyz.com weight:50
test.xyz.com weight:50
```

The problem is I want add one more record set, with higher weights, and decrease the weight of the above mentioned record sets, for example:

```
 test.xyz.com weight:30
 test.xyz.com weight:30
 test.xyz.com weight:40
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using Python Boto3 module? I did not find any API for doing it.

Comment: See [change_resource_record_sets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html?highlight=route#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets).